# Implementing locking mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to use mysql row level lock. I can't lock complete table. I want to avoid two process processing two different message for server at same time. 
What I thought that I can have some table called:
`server_lock` and if one process start working on server it will insert a row in the table.

Problem with this approach is that if application crashes. We need to remove the lock manually. 
Is there a way I may row level lock and lock will get released if application is crashing ?

**Edit**
I am using C++ as language. 
My application is similar to message queue. But difference is that there is two queue which are getting populated by one process for each queue. After action if action belong to same object and both are processing same object it may result in wrong data. So I want a locking mechanism b/w these two queue so that both processor don't modify same object at same time.

Comment: Do you have one application with two queues or two applications with one queu for each?

Comment: two application with one queue each.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two ways:

- Implement some error handler on your program where you remove the lock. Without knowing anything about your program it is hard to say how to do this, but most languages have some method to do some work before exiting upon a crash. This is dangerous, because a crash happens when something is not right. If you continue to do any work, it is possible that you corrupt the database or something like that.
- Periodically update the lock. Add a thread on your program that periodically reacquires the lock, or reacquire the lock in some loop you are doing. Then, when a lock is not updated in a while, you know that it belonged to a program that crashed.

Comment: I updated question with more details. Is this information helpful?